# nginx basic auth permissions for user

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, auth

Можно ли сделать ограничение пользователям к ресурсам приложения используя nginx + basic auth. Я хочу сделать что бы юзер client после авторизации имел доступ только к некоторым ресурсам, /wp/modules, /wp/desi, /wp/assets. А пользователь admin имел доступ ко всему.

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать использовать [для разных location](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) разные файлы с паролями?
Например вот такой конфиг у меня прекрасно сработал в тестовой песочнице. В корень пускает и admin и user, а в /test_admin при попытке войти user-ом запрашивает пароль.

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        auth_basic  "rootdir";
        auth_basic_user_file "/usr/share/nginx/root.auth";
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location /test_admin {
            root   /usr/share/nginx;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            auth_basic  "admindir";
            auth_basic_user_file "/usr/share/nginx/admin.auth";
        }
    }
```

Соответственно содержимое /usr/share/nginx/root.auth:

```
admin:yIFz/FsHJVxBA
user:ywRtY7HxsLbzk
```

И содержимое /usr/share/nginx/admin.auth:

```
admin:yIFz/FsHJVxBA
```

Пароль admin: 12345, user: 67890

Comment: а как тогда другой юзер будет попадать в локейшн?